# Prevent account lockout by utilities like ldapsearch

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I've setup account locking in AD after 5 unsuccessful login attempts. The problem I've found is that using ldapsearch utility anyone can lock any account in the domain, if the right username is known:

```
ldapsearch -D someaccount@somedamain.com -w IntentionallyWrongPassword
```

This potentially is a bad thing. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

These Intruder Detection Methodologies are ALWAYS an possible denial of service attack regardless of if it is LDAP or done at any login screen.

Using techniques such as Multi-factor authentication may be a possible alternative.